# How do I change the page load Timeouts in Watir-Webdriver (timeout in .click method)

Tags: webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I have the following code

```
browser.link(:text => 'Generate Report').click  
browser.radio(:value => 'byTotalValue').wait_until_present(180)
```

which requests that a report be generated and then waits for the report by looking for an element on the report page. The report can take upwards of 2 minutes to appear.

What is happening is a Timeout::Error is being raised from the click method after 60 seconds. I suspect that Watir-Webdriver has implemented some form of wait for page load within the click method but I don't see a way to adjust the value.

Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: I found the following discussion concerning internal timeouts for selenium. This seems to be my problem however when trying to use the code recommended to adjust the internal timeouts for watir-webdriver I get a "connection refused" exception from net/http.rb.

Comment: [see internal timeouts here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I'd try upping the client timeout:

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 180 # seconds – default is 60

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :http_client => client
```

Comment: Great job Alister, I've give you 10 upclicks for that if the system would let me

Comment: How do I set the timeout to infinity ? -1 perhaps ?

Comment: AlisterScott  - sorry for the shameless advertising. Can you please help me with this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423800/cannot-click-html-element-with-watir . thanks!!!

Answer (score 16):

Update: This monkey patch has been merged into watir-webdriver and so will no longer be needed in watir-webdriver v0.6.5. You will be able to set the timeout using:

```rb
Watir.default_timeout = 90
```

from: [Is it possible to globally increase Watir-Webdriver when_present wait time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994867/is-it-possible-to-globally-increase-watir-webdriver-when-present-wait-time)

Comment: Just to be clear, the option to adjust the default timeout in Watir will not affect the client timeout that was the concern in this question.