# Set page load timeout

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I use watir webdriver gem with chromedriver. I know (https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=9#c25) that in new version 2.1 of chromedriver there is a special page load timeout. How can I set it from ruby code?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014121/how-do-i-change-the-page-load-timeouts-in-watir-webdriver-timeout-in-click-met

Comment: no, that is not about page load timeout.

Answer (score 5):

There is a page load timeout that specifies how long to wait for a page to load before throwing an exception.

This is set within the underlying selenium-webdriver object:

```
browser.driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 10 #seconds
```

For example, an exception will now be thrown when a page does not load fast enough:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.driver.manage.timeouts.page_load = 0
browser.goto 'http://www.google.ca'
#=> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError
```