# continued example - cannot find watir element

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

In [Cannot click html element with watir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423800/cannot-click-html-element-with-watir), i was trying to click an element which gives me the row below:

[image]

I am not able to find the three dropdown lists which you see in the image above.
How do I do it ? Each time, the id of the dropdown elements changes.

For example, the middle one html code is:

```
<td>
<select id="filtersJob6_intrinsic_enumOperator" name="filtersJob6_intrinsic_enumOperator" onchange="if(top.document.getElementById('filtersJob6_intrinsic_enumOperator').value=='isNull'||top.document.getElementById('filtersJob6_intrinsic_enumOperator').value=='isNotNull'){top.document.getElementById('filtersJob6_intrinsic_operand1Container').style.display='none';}else{top.document.getElementById('filtersJob6_intrinsic_operand1Container').style.display='inline';}">
<option value="equals" selected="selected">equals</option>
<option value="notEqual">not equals</option>
<option value="isNull">is not set</option>
<option value="isNotNull">is set</option>
</select>
</td>
```

The id `id="filtersJob6_intrinsic_enumOperator"` can have any number 4,7,6,5 etc.

How do I make the watir find this element ?

**EDIT -**

```
Here is the code for the first dropdown:

<select id="filtersJob3_intrinsic_name" name="filtersJob3_intrinsic_name" onchange="var shown=0;top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operator').style.display='none';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1').style.display='none';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand2').style.display='none';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_dateOperator').style.display='none';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_enumOperator').style.display='none';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_listOperator').style.display='none';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_uuidOperator').style.display='none';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_datehelp1').style.display='none';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_datehelp2').style.display='none';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1abortStatus').style.display='none';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1outcome').style.display='none';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1priority').style.display='none';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1status').style.display='none';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1errorCode').style.display='none';if(top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_name').value=='abortStatus'){shown=1;top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_enumOperator').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1abortStatus').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand2Container').style.display='none';}if(top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_name').value=='outcome'){shown=1;top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_enumOperator').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1outcome').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand2Container').style.display='none';}if(top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_name').value=='priority'){shown=1;top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_enumOperator').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1priority').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand2Container').style.display='none';}if(top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_name').value=='status'){shown=1;top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_enumOperator').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1status').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand2Container').style.display='none';}if(top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_name').value=='errorCode'){shown=1;top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_enumOperator').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1errorCode').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand2Container').style.display='none';}if(top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_name').value=='jobId'){shown=1;top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_uuidOperator').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand2Container').style.display='none';}if(top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_name').value=='createTime'){shown=1;top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_dateOperator').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_datehelp1').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand2').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_datehelp2').style.display='inline';}if(top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_name').value=='finish'){shown=1;top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_dateOperator').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_datehelp1').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand2').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_datehelp2').style.display='inline';}if(top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_name').value=='modifyTime'){shown=1;top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_dateOperator').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_datehelp1').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand2').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_datehelp2').style.display='inline';}if(top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_name').value=='start'){shown=1;top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_dateOperator').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_datehelp1').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand2').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_datehelp2').style.display='inline';}if(!shown){top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operator').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operator').onchange();top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand1').style.display='inline';top.document.getElementById('filtersJob3_intrinsic_operand2').style.display='inline';}">

  <option value="abortStatus" selected="selected">Abort Status</option>
  <option value="abortedBy">Aborted By</option>
  <option value="createTime">Create Time</option>
  <option value="directoryName">Directory Name</option>
  <option value="elapsedTime">Elapsed Time</option>
  <option value="errorCode">Error Code</option>
  <option value="errorMessage">Error Message</option>
  <option value="finish">Finish Date &amp; Time</option>
  <option value="credentialName">Impersonation Credential</option>
  <option value="jobId">Job ID</option>
  <option value="jobName">Job Name</option>
  <option value="lastModifiedBy">Last Modified By</option>
  <option value="launchedByUser">Launched By User</option>
  <option value="licenseWaitTime">License Wait Time</option>
  <option value="liveProcedure">Live Procedure</option>
  <option value="liveSchedule">Live Schedule</option>
  <option value="modifyTime">Modify Time</option>
  <option value="outcome">Outcome</option>
  <option value="owner">Owner</option>
  <option value="priority">Priority</option>
  <option value="procedureName">Procedure Name</option>
  <option value="projectName">Project Name</option>
  <option value="resourceWaitTime">Resource Wait Time</option>
  <option value="runAsUser">Run As User</option>
  <option value="scheduleName">Schedule Name</option>
  <option value="start">Start Date &amp; Time</option>
  <option value="stateName">State Name</option>
  <option value="status">Status</option>
  <option value="totalWaitTime">Total Wait Time</option>
  <option value="workspaceWaitTime">Workspace Wait Time</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression in your locator:

```
browser.select_list(:id => /filtersJob\d+_intrinsic_enumOperator/).select value_to_select
```

In this example, the regular expression is denoted by opening and closing  forward slashes, and the digit within the original string is replaced with `\d+`, which means "one or more digits".

**EDIT:**

Given this minimal HTML snippet:

```
<select id="filtersJob6_intrinsic_enumOperator">
  <option value="isNull">is not set</option>
  <option value="isNotNull">is set</option>
</select>
```

Use `select` to choose on option based on text:

```
b.select_list(:id => /filtersJob\d+_intrinsic_enumOperator/).select 'is set'
```

Use `select_value` to choose an option based on the `value` attribute:

```
b.select_list(:id => /filtersJob\d+_intrinsic_enumOperator/).select_value 'isNotNull'
```

Comment: `browser.select_list(:id => /filtersJob\d+_intrinsic_enumOperator/).select 'jobName'` Error - `no_value_found': "jobName" not found in select list (Watir::Exception::NoValueFoundException). Adding the javascript and html code now.

Comment: Answer updated.  You want to use `select_value` if you are trying to select based on the `value` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I get the error `no_value_found': "jobName" not found in select list (Watir::Exception::NoValueFoundException)`.

Comment: You're supplied  2 HTML snippets.  The <select> tags have different id attributes.  Make sure you are accessing the correct element.

Comment: Yes, each time, the number in the id will be different as mentioned. `o = browser.select_list(:id => /filtersJob\d+_intrinsic_enumOperator/).include? 'jobName'; puts o` Output - false

Comment: [`Select::include?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Select#include%3F-instance_method) will return true "if the select list has one or more options where text or label matches the given value".  So, that won't work for `value` attributes.  And--based on your HTML--`<select id="filtersJob\d+_intrinsic_enumOperator">` doesn't contain `<option value="jobName">Job Name</option>`.  That option is in `<select id="filtersJobd\+_intrinsic_name">`.

Comment: my bad. `browser.select_list(:id => /filtersJob\d+_intrinsic_name/).select 'Job Name'` Does nothing. How do I find that element ?